# angular $http post: can't get the request parameters

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, angular-http

I'm a beginner... creating a crud application with angular node and mysql

for some reason I can't get the data like `console.log(request.body.name)` or `console.log(request.body.description)` I get 505 error.. where as if I simply print `console.log('any message')` this gets displayed without any error.

I've this bind `ng-click="editProductCategory()"` on a button

bewlow is `editProductCategory()` method

```
$scope.editProductCategory = function (){

    productCategoryService.updateProductCategory($scope.productCategoryData, productCategoryService.getIdFromUri())
        .success(function (data) {
        if(data && data.status && data.status == 'successful'){
            alert('updated successfully');
        }
        })
        .error(function (err, status) {
        console.log('********************************');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('-------------------------------');
        console.log(status);
        console.log('********************************');
        });
    }
```

and here is my `productCategoryService.updateProductCategory`

```
updateProductCategory: function (productCategory, productCategoryId) {
            console.log(productCategory.name);
            console.log(productCategory.description);
            console.log(productCategoryId);
            return $http.post('/updateProductCategory', {
                name: productCategory.name,
                description: productCategory.description,
                categoryId: productCategoryId
            });

        }
```

Here is the route configuration

```
this.routeTable.push({
        requestType: 'post',
        requestUrl: '/updateProductCategory',
        callbackFunction: function(request, response)
        {
            console.log('/******* arrived successfully ********/');
            //console.log(request.body.description + " no errors");
            //console.log(request.param());

            response.json()
        }
    });

this.routeTable.forEach(function(route){
        if(route.requestType == 'get')
        {
            this.app.get(route.requestUrl, route.callbackFunction)
        }
        else if(route.requestType == 'post' || route.requestType == 'POST   ')
        {
            this.app.post(route.requestUrl, route.callbackFunction);
        }
        else if(route.requestType == 'delete'){}
    });
```

any idea?

Comment: I don't see which line of your code breaks or doesn't work as you expected, can you point that out?

Comment: the lines that are commented in `this.routeTable.push()` this one `console.log(request.body.description + ' without errors')` these are not working

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post` will send your data as JSON, so if you are using Express, you need use the [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware to parse the request body.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: thanks @Rebornix.. but app has been generated by using `express -e` and it already have that middle-ware installed.